# How can i get the value of a pkey for a record just inserted (autoincrement)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I'm subsequently inserting a single record in two tables. With the first insert i put the record in the main table, where the primary key value gets generated. Now i need to put some fields of this record in another table including the key value of the main table. How do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`" will return the last autoincrement ID generated.

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() is thread-safe. It's stored on a per-connection basis, so insert statements from others connections will not affect its value.

Comment: If akosch is sharing connections between threads (yuck) the insert may need to be in a stored function that returns the last_insert_id().

Comment: Well, I would better redesign the application to not share the same opened connection between several threads, unless he has a good reason for doing so.